# Relation between the homotopy classes of map $S^n \to S^2$ and $T^n \to S^2$ for $n=2,3$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request, physics

I wonder if there is any relation between the homotopy classes of map $S^n \to S^2$, and the homotopy classes of map $T^n \to S^2$, where $n=2,3$.

In particular, I want to understand the below quotes from the physics paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3427 :

> The classification of the map $T^2 \to S^2$ is equivalent to the
> homotopy group $\pi_2(S^2)$ classifying the map $S^2\to S^2$, because
> **the nontrivial cycles on the torus do not affect the homotopy classes
> of the map.** It is well known that the winding number of this map is
> the same as the first Chern number.
>
> However, there is a subtle difference between the map $T^3 \to S^2$
> and the map $S^3 \to S^2$. The maps from $T^3\to S^2$ is more
> complicated than the maps $S^3\to S^2$, **because there are 3
> independent 2D torus inside $T^3$ and each of them may has nonzero
> Chern numbers.** For $\mu = x,y,z$, let $C_\mu$ be the Chern number when
> taking $k_\mu$ to be constant. It is pointed out by Pontryagin that if
> $C_\mu \neq 0$, then the Hopf index, defined as
> $$\mathcal H =\frac{1}{32\pi^2} \int_{T^3} A \wedge dA,$$
> (I will not quote the
> definition of $A$) is no longer integer-valued and take values in the
> finite group $\mathbb Z_{2\times \mathrm{gcd}(C_x, C_y, C_z)}$.

Could you explain why the bold part holds? Also, (mathematical) references on this topic is appreciated. I have basic knowledge of algebraic topology and differential geometry.

Comment: For $n=2$, I think they are saying that because $S^1 \vee S^1$ is one dimensional, every map $T^2 \rightarrow S^2$ may be homotoped so that the wedge gets sent to a point. Maps of the latter form are classified by maps $S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ because $T^2 / S^1 \vee S^1 = S^2$. Now there is a subtlety. Just because you are homotopic to such a map does not necessarily mean the homotopy classification is the same. This is because $1$-cells in $T^2$ become $2$-cells after crossing with an interval, so they can't be assumed to get sent to a point.

Comment: It turns out that the homotopy classification is the same. Really it comes down to the result that for an $n$-manifold, the $n$th cohomology is naturally isomorphic to maps $M \rightarrow S^n$. The proof of this is homotopy theoretic appealing to Eilenberg-Maclane spaces. In low dimensional cases, it is probably not difficult to give a geometric argument.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks for your comment! Regarding the first comment, I think considering $T^2/S^1\wedge S^1$ is natural, and it is what the authors intended for. Regarding the second comment, what keyword should I look for to study why $n$-th cohomology is naturally isomorphic to homotopy classes of $M\to S^n$?

Comment: I think you are mistaking $\wedge$ and $\vee$. $\vee$ is the wedge and is what should be considered here. The theorem is called the Hopf theorem.